# How to write multiply condition in several line without invalid syntax error in Python

Tags: python

The following code gives me error:

```
    if self.from_position in self.supporters or 
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code:

```
def validate_move_piece(self):
    if self.from_position in self.supporters or 
    (self.turn == 'X' and self.from_position == self.player_x) or 
    (self.turn == 'Y' and self.from_position == self.player_y) or 
    (self.last_position == self.from_position):
        return True
    else:
        self.error = ERROR_MOVE_FORMAT 
        return False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put parentheses around the whole if statement condition, like this:

```
>>> if (True or
... False or
... True):
...     print 'woo'
... 
woo
```

(This works in python files as well as the interpreter.)

Comment: Thanks But I'm still confusing about under what circumstance the parenthesis can be omitted

Comment: What are you confused about? The outer parens can be omitted for a single line or if you use the backslash method. You can use the outer parens for a single line statement as well, though that will have no effect.

Answer (score 4):

Add backslash \ in the end of the line.

```
if 1==1 and\
2==2:
  print 'hi'
```

Comment: +1 A backslash is *valid*, but parentheses should be preferred because it's easy to accidentally leave a space or other invisible character after the backslash. Also, parentheses give the reader more visual clues about compound expressions than a backslash at the end of the line. Finally, what if you want to put a comment on that line?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `()` to separate multiple lines.

For e.g. your code will be:

```
def validate_move_piece(self):
    if (self.from_position in self.supporters or 
    (self.turn == 'X' and self.from_position == self.player_x) or 
    (self.turn == 'Y' and self.from_position == self.player_y) or 
    (self.last_position == self.from_position)):
        return True
    else:
        self.error = ERROR_MOVE_FORMAT 
        return False
```

Look, I have engulfed the `if` statement with a `()`